# Build own LineageOS from Source code generates error

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, android-source, lineageos

I am trying to build lineage os 17.0 for my old Samsung Galaxy a5 2016 (a5xelte). It's my first time building an Android Rom from Source code. I got past most of the errors i was getting, but theres one I'm getting when building the Rom i can't get past. I couldn't find anything on google, so i thought maybe one of you can help me. I'm always getting this error after a few seconds of building.

```
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=10
LINEAGE_VERSION=17.0-20191101-UNOFFICIAL-a5xelte
TARGET_PRODUCT=lineage_a5xelte
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=userdebug
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv8-a
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=cortex-a53
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-5.3.0-19-generic-x86_64-Ubuntu-19.10
HOST_CROSS_OS=windows
HOST_CROSS_ARCH=x86
HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=QP1A.191005.007
OUT_DIR=out
PRODUCT_SOONG_NAMESPACES=vendor/samsung/a5xelte vendor/samsung/a5xelte
============================================
[100% 2/2] out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build out/soong/build.ninja
FAILED: out/soong/build.ninja
out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build -t -l out/.module_paths/Android.bp.list -b out/soong -n out -d out/soong/build.ninja.d -globFile out/soong/.bootstrap/build-globs.ninja -o out/soong/build.ninja Android.bp
error: system/core/init/Android.bp:95:1: "libinit" depends on undefined module "libinit_sec"
17:21:59 soong bootstrap failed with: exit status 1

#### failed to build some targets (7 seconds) ####
```

Thanks for your help.